# Interchange order of integrals and summation.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, summation

I would like to know, if we have:
$$I=\int_{0}^{a} (\ln y)\Big[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!} y^{(j+1)b-1}\Big]\,dy,~~~~a,b>0$$
then interchange order of integral and summation, 
 $$I=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\int_{0}^{a} (\ln y) y^{(j+1)b-1}\,dy$$
is valid?

Comment: In general, you can't interchange them. You could try to define $u_n(y):=\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\ln(y)y^{(j+1)b-1}$ and check a theorem like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem . You might like to try it yourself first?